# Can I over ride methods in "object classes"

Tags: javascript

ES6 allows you do something like:

```
class bla {
  method(){}
}

class something extends bla {
  method(){ super() }
}
```

Can I get away with something like this in:

```
var bla = { method: function(){} };
var something ._extends(bla, { ... });
```

I am looking to try and over ride `method()`, how ever it seems the only way to actually do this is to use prototypes. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to create an object which inherits from `bla`, but overriding some property.

You can use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create):

```
var something = Object.create(bla, {
  method: {configurable: true, writable:true, enumerable: true, value: ...}
});
```

Or [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
var something = Object.assign(Object.create(bla), {
  method: ...
});
```

Comment: In the "sub class" can I call something like `super()` in the child method function thus calling the parent? thus using the concept of "inheritance" and method over riding?

Comment: @KyleAdams Not directly. But you can use `Object.getPrototypeOf` to get the [[Prototype]] and call the method there. Or use Proxy objects. Or remove the own property, call it (then it will be the inherited one) and add the own one back.